# use getParameter to return value of the button

Tags: java, html, servlets

How can we bind together button in html form with servlet?

For example, I tried to do so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="insert" name="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

and in servlet:

```
if(request.getParameter("submitBtn").equals("insert")) {
...
}
```

but NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: How are you submitting the form? The button param is not getting submitted with your mechanism that is why you not getting that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.getParameter("submitBtn")` returns null if the request does not contain such a parameter, hence a `NullPointerException` is thrown if you compare the null value with `"insert"`.

To avoid the exception rewrite your test as

```
if ("insert".equals(request.getParameter("submitBtn")) {
```